# Kendo-UI jQuery Menu Item Splitter

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I am currently using Kendo-UI 2021.2.616, specifically the Bootstrap SASS theme.

Is there a specific class or object definition that I can use to create a splitter in a menu item dropdown?

What I'm currently doing is adding an item where the text is empty and there is styling to give it the appearance that the item is just a horizontal line. Example:

```js
$('#menu').kendoMenu({
  dataSource: new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    data: [
      {
        text: 'Dropdown',
        items: [
          {
            text: 'Item 1',
            url: '#/'
          },
          {
            text: 'Item 2',
            url: '#/'
          },
          {
            attr: {
              style: 'border-top: 1px solid #000; height: 1px; margin: 0 0.25rem;'
            },
            text: ''
          },
          {
            text: 'Item 3',
            url: '#/'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  })
});
```

Fiddle: https://dojo.telerik.com/eFiHUMEx

My issue is that my workaround smells like a hack. I feel like the Kendo-UI library would have a menu item splitter defined, but looking through the documentation I cannot find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your workaround is not a hack. That is basically how you add a separator, some CSS magic. Since you are looking for a defined Kendo separator. Change:

```
attr: {
  style: 'border-top: 1px solid #000; height: 1px; margin: 0 0.25rem;'
},
```

to this:

```
attr: {
  class: 'k-separator'
},
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: I'm aware that separators are usually created via CSS (unless you use an `<hr />`), what I was looking for was the Kendo-UI class definition. So thank you for providing me with the `k-separator` class. The only adjustment that I made is that I removed the `attr` property all together and instead I'm leveraging the `cssClass` property on the root object: `{ cssClass: 'k-separator', text: '' }`